# Is it possible to print duotone gradient images using two pantone neon colors?

Tags: print-design, images, prepress

What should I be aware of and be careful with when preparing the image?

Comment: This is probably something best asked of a print provider.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to print duotone gradient images using two pantone neon colors?

Yes.

> What should I be aware of and be careful with when preparing the image?

You should be aware that there's no way to reproduce the exact colors short of printing it. So you'll want to set up your file, but be on site for the press check to ensure it's what you're hoping it will end up being. Otherwise, it's going to be mostly guessing (which can be an interesting way to handle it too...sometimes the unexpected is part of the design process).